# JavaScript FabricJs put image to canvas view

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

I want to create a circle and an arrow form using Fabric.js, so that for instance if one clicks on the arrow button, one should be able to draw an arrow (with the current selected width and height), same for the circle. The regarding html Looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group-toggle toolbar-left-btns" data-toggle="buttons">
    <h4 class="h4-color-white" id="current-shape-name" style="display:none;"></h4>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-md btn-md btn-tool-margin-left" title="Create an arrow object"  id="drawing-arrow-shape">
        <input type="radio" name="drawing-shape">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-md btn-tool-margin-left" title="Create a circle object" id="drawing-circle-shape">
        <input type="radio" name="drawing-shape">
        <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
    </label>
</div>
```

Basically a selection if one uses the arrow or circle form. I won't post the full script since ist really Long, currently I am able to select a Color and a brush width and paint on my canvas. That works, so Keep that in mind. I am just not "able" to create a circle and an arrow. In the following part of my script I am selecting of the if its an arrow or circle (the selection works) and if selected to "draw" that arrow or circle in my canvas, it draws Right after selecting a mix between an arrow and a cube, any idea what I am missing. Nor do I get an error message.

```
const canvasRenderer = {

    render() {
        this.initCanvas();
    },

    elements: {
        ...
        canvas: '',
        isDown: null,
        circle: null,
        circleOrigX: null,
        circleOrigY: null,
        startX: null,
        startY: null,
        id: {
            ...
            drawingArrowShape: $('#drawing-arrow-shape'),
            drawingCircleShape: $('#drawing-circle-shape'),
            imgInput: $('#img-input'),
        },
        tags: {
            html: $('html')
        }
    },

    propToolRadio() {
        this.elements.id.drawingArrowShape.prop('checked', false);
        this.elements.id.drawingCircleShape.prop('checked', false);
        this.elements.id.drawingArrowShape.parent().removeClass('active');
        this.elements.id.drawingCircleShape.parent().removeClass('active');
    },

    recOnArrow(canvas) {
        this.elements.id.drawingArrowShape.change((e) => {
            canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
            this.elements.id.currentShapeName.innerHTML = 'Arrow';
            canvas.off('mouse:down', this.onCircleMouseDown(e));
            canvas.off('mouse:move', this.onCircleMouseMove(e));
            canvas.off('mouse:up', this.onCircleMouseUp(e));
            canvas.on('mouse:down', this.onArrowMouseDown(e));
            canvas.on('mouse:move', this.onArrowMouseMove(e));
            canvas.on('mouse:up', this.onArrowMouseUp(e));
            this.recCanvas(canvas);
        });
    },

    recOnCircle(canvas) {
        this.elements.id.drawingCircleShape.change((e) => {
            canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
            this.elements.id.currentShapeName.innerHTML = 'Circle';
            canvas.on('mouse:down', this.onCircleMouseDown(e));
            canvas.on('mouse:move', this.onCircleMouseMove(e));
            canvas.on('mouse:up', this.onCircleMouseUp(e));
            canvas.off('mouse:down', this.onArrowMouseDown(e));
            canvas.off('mouse:move', this.onArrowMouseMove(e));
            canvas.off('mouse:up', this.onArrowMouseUp(e));
            this.recCanvas(canvas);
        });
    },

    onArrowMouseDown(o) {
        let pointer = this.elements.canvas.getPointer(o.e);
        this.elements.startX = pointer.x;
        this.elements.startY = pointer.y;
        this.recCanvas(this.elements.canvas);
    },

    onArrowMouseUp(o) {
        let pointer = this.elements.canvas.getPointer(o.e);
        let endX = pointer.x;
        let endY = pointer.y;
        this.showArrow(
            this.elements.startX,
            this.elements.startY,
            endX,
            endY,
            this.elements.canvas
        );
        this.recCanvas(this.elements.canvas);
    },

    onArrowMouseMove(e) {
    },

    onCircleMouseDown(o) {
        this.elements.isDown = true;
        let pointer = this.elements.canvas.getPointer(o.e);
        this.elements.circleOrigX = pointer.x;
        this.elements.circleOrigY = pointer.y;
        if (!this.elements.circle) {
            this.elements.circle = new fabric.Circle({
                left: this.elements.circleOrigX,
                top: this.elements.circleOrigY,
                originX: 'center',
                originY: 'center',
                radius: 0,
                fill: '',
                stroke: this.elements.id.drawingColorEl.value,
                strokeWidth: parseInt(this.elements.id.drawingLineWidthEl.value, 10) || 1,
                selectable: true
            });
            this.elements.canvas.add(this.elements.circle);
        }
        this.recCanvas(this.elements.canvas);
    },

    onCircleMouseMove(o) {
        console.log("onCircleMouseMove");
        if (!this.elements.isDown) return;
        let pointer = this.elements.canvas.getPointer(o.e);
        this.elements.circle.set({
            radius: Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow(
                    (this.elements.circleOrigX - pointer.x), 2
                ) + Math.pow((this.elements.circleOrigY - pointer.y), 2)
            )
        });
        this.elements.canvas.renderAll();
    },

    onCircleMouseUp(o) {
        console.log("onCircleMouseUp");
        this.elements.isDown = false;
        this.elements.circle = null;
    },

    showArrow(fromx, fromy, tox, toy, canvas) {
        console.log("showArrow");
        let angle = Math.atan2(toy - fromy, tox - fromx);
        let headlen = 15; // arrow head size
        // bring the line end back some to account for arrow head.
        tox = tox - (headlen) * Math.cos(angle);
        toy = toy - (headlen) * Math.sin(angle);
        // calculate the points.
        let points = [{
            x: fromx, // start point
            y: fromy
        }, {
            x: fromx - (headlen / 4) * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 2),
            y: fromy - (headlen / 4) * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 2)
        }, {
            x: tox - (headlen / 4) * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 2),
            y: toy - (headlen / 4) * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 2)
        }, {
            x: tox - (headlen) * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 2),
            y: toy - (headlen) * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 2)
        }, {
            x: tox + (headlen) * Math.cos(angle), // tip
            y: toy + (headlen) * Math.sin(angle)
        }, {
            x: tox - (headlen) * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 2),
            y: toy - (headlen) * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 2)
        }, {
            x: tox - (headlen / 4) * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 2),
            y: toy - (headlen / 4) * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 2)
        }, {
            x: fromx - (headlen / 4) * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 2),
            y: fromy - (headlen / 4) * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 2)
        }, {
            x: fromx,
            y: fromy
        }];

        let pline = new fabric.Polyline(points, {
            fill: 'black',
            stroke: this.elements.id.drawingColorEl.value,
            opacity: 1,
            // strokeWidth: 2,
            strokeWidth: parseInt(this.elements.id.drawingLineWidthEl.value, 10) || 1,
            originX: 'left',
            originY: 'top',
            selectable: true
        });

        canvas.add(pline);
        canvas.renderAll();
    },

    /**
     * TODO on mdified, moving, rotating, scaling method to call only once
     */
    recOnEvent(canvas) {
        let isObjectMoving = false;
        canvas.on('path:created', () => {
            this.recCanvas(canvas)
        });
        canvas.on('object.added', () => {
            this.recCanvas(canvas)
        });
        canvas.on('object:modified', () => {
            isObjectMoving = true;
        });
        canvas.on('object:moving', () => {
            isObjectMoving = true;
        });
        canvas.on('object:removed', () => {
            this.recCanvas(canvas)
        });
        canvas.on('object:rotating', () => {
            isObjectMoving = true;
        });
        canvas.on('object:scaling', () => {
            isObjectMoving = true;
        });
        this.elements.id.canvasContainer.click(() => {
            this.recCanvas(canvas);
        });
        canvas.on('mouse:up', () => {
            if (isObjectMoving) {
                isObjectMoving = false;
                this.recCanvas(canvas); // fire this if finished
            }
        });
    },
};

$(document).ready(() => {
    canvasRenderer.render();
});
```

Comment: It's hard to help you with a lot of missing pisses in your code. Can you normalized your code and create a fiddle?

Comment: Way to much code! please reduce the scope to only one problem

Comment: try `canvas.off('mouse:down', this.onCircleMouseDown);` for every thing. don't pass e as argument, you are calling the function there.

Comment: @Durga hi I tried that I removed the e Parameter, but I get this error `cannt read property canvas of undefined`  `onArrowMouseDown: function onArrowMouseDown(o) {
        var pointer = this.elements.canvas.getPointer(o);`

Comment: `canvas.off('mouse:down', this.onCircleMouseDown.bind(this))`

Comment: @Durga ok Errors are gone but I do not get a circle nor an arrow if I try to drag

Comment: try to debug whether the functions getting called or not.

Comment: @Durge if I select the tool and click on the canvas, it runs through this function `onArrowMouseDown` if I release the mouse it runs through the `showArrow`function i somehow do not get any mousemove logs if I click on the canvas and try to draw a circle or an arrow